# Сайт не видит шрифты Google

Tags: html, css, шрифты, link, href

Помогите решить проблему, не могу никак разобраться, не работает никак. Привожу конкретику:
Загрузил шрифт от Google Fonts -  font-family: "Wix Madefor Display", подключил его в header:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Wix+Madefor+Display:wght@400..800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Но сайт отказывается его видеть. Что Google Chrome, что в Opera, что в Edge... Классы с ним указывается, например верно:

```
.font-header {
    font-family: "Wix Madefor Display";
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.1rem;
}
```

Причём есть ещё один подключенный таким образом шрифт от Google - IBM Plex и он работает нормально. В чём причина отображения не могу понять. В консоли разработчика - указывается, что шрифт применён к тексту, но это ложь т. к. текст отображается совсем другим шрифтом.
Перед стилями сделан reset стилей браузеров.
Прикладываю скриншот.
Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]